# Advanced ASP.NET WebGrid - Dynamic Columns and Rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I'm trying to create a WebGrid which has to be very dynamic. The columns are defined in a list, which I've done like so:

```
@{
    List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    foreach (var column in Model.Columns)
    {
        columns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName = column.Name, Header = column.Name });
    }
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: columns)
```

All well and good, but the problem I have is with the rows. I'll try and explain...

For this question let's say we have two columns for **Name** and **Address**.

I have a collection of row objects, lets say SearchResult objects. A SearchResult contains a Dictionary of any number of attributes, such as Name, Address, Phone, Height, Bra Size, or anything (think of the EAV pattern). I need to access the attributes based on Column Name.

I figured I could do this using **format**, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want something like this:

```
columns.Add(new WebGridColumn() { ColumnName = column.Name, Header =
    column.Header, Format = @<text>@item.Attributes[column.Name]</text> });
```

This sort of works but despite creating the format for the separate columns, the rows get populated with only the last column's format. i.e.:

```
Name            Address
1 Main Street   1 Main Street
45 Paradise Av  45 Paradise Av
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work if you leave out the "ColumnName" (superfluous anyway), and also make the dynamic expression a bit more explicit:

```
columns.Add(
   new WebGridColumn() { 
      Header = column.Header, 
      Format = (item) => @Html.Raw("<text>" + @item.Attributes[column.Name] + "</text>")
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to reference variables. You need to have the Format property in terms of the other properties of the WebGridColumn.  This is how I would do it:

```
@{
    List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    foreach (var column in Model.Columns)
    {
        var col = new WebGridColumn();
        col.Header = column.Name;
        col.Format = (item) => @Html.Raw("<text>" + @item.Attributes[col.Header] +  "</text>");
        columns.Add(col);
    }
}
```